# Problems with simultaneous insertion/deletion of rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days now. I need to simultaneously delete and insert some rows in an UITableView inside a beginUpdates/endUpdates block, but some of the inserted rows have an index that surpasses the original table view element count. I took sample code from Apple documentation on batch insertion and deletion and modified it in order to cause the same problem, here is the code:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
        states = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Arizona", @"California", @"New Jersey", @"Washington", nil] retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [states release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [states count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [states removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [states removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [states removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    [states insertObject:@"Alaska" atIndex:1];
    [states insertObject:@"Georgia" atIndex:1];
    [states insertObject:@"Wisconsin" atIndex:1];

    NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
                             nil];

    NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0],
                             [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0],
                             nil];

    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;

    [tv beginUpdates];
    [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [tv endUpdates];
}

@end
```

When I run this and tap any row, I get the following exception:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:386
Uncaught exception: Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source.
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with this code that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Since you are in essence replacing rows, why dont u just reload those index paths instead of deleting and reinserting?...just a though

Comment: Because this is a simpler example. On my real app, the number of rows deleted and inserted is not always the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation for `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` clearly states that deletion come before insertion in an update block:

> Note the behavior of this method when it is called in an animation block defined by the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods. UITableView defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions of rows or sections. This happens regardless of ordering of the insertion and deletion method calls.

More details in the Table View Programming Guide:

> However, this is not the order in which UITableView completes the operations. It defers any insertions of rows or sections until after it has handled the deletions of rows or sections. The table view behaves the same way with reloading methods called inside an update block—the reload takes place with respect to the indexes of rows and sections before the animation block is executed. This behavior happens regardless of the ordering of the insertion, deletion, and reloading method calls.
>
> Deletion and reloading operations within an animation block specify which rows and sections in the original table should be removed or reloaded; insertions specify which rows and sections should be added to the resulting table. The index paths used to identify sections and rows follow this model. Inserting or removing an item in a mutable array, on the other hand, may affect the array index used for the successive insertion or removal operation; for example, if you insert an item at a certain index, the indexes of all subsequent items in the array are incremented.

Comment: Yes, I read that. But it also states that the indexes (indices?) should pertain to the table state BEFORE the begin/endUpdates, which is what I'm doing... Isn't it?

Comment: Well, deletions should use the indexPaths before any updates, insertions should use the indexPaths after all deletions have been applied. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the second paragraph, the insertion index paths should be considered AFTER the deletion. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to insert or delete rows,  technically totalAddedRows = addingRows-deleteRows(here 3-3=0), So just updates rows or reload table the data will automatically change.

In case totalAddedRows is +ve then insert new rows and if it is in negative then delete rows. Dont do add and delete simultaneously.

Note: Your application getting crash because if you call insert Row then total array count is 3 only.